# confusion about FreeSWITCH callID variables

Tags: freeswitch

I'm a bit confusing about the channel variables that represent the call ID.

I find that there are three variables, 1) Unique-ID 2) Channel-Call-UUID 3) variable_sip_call_id, what is the different between this.

The value of Channel-Call-UUID seems to be stable during the entire call, the value of Unique-ID in the begin it is the same as Channel-Call-UUID but when bridging it changes it value to another ID, then it comes back to the beginning value, i.m not clear when and why.

The variable variable_sip_call_id many time don't have any value, and also it changes the value when bridging and then comes back to the previous value.

I have looked for an explanation in FreeSWITCH wiki, but don't find.
Can someone give a good explanation about this variables,what is their purpose, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the mailing list:

> By Brian West:
>
> 1. Unique-ID is the session UUID, this won't change at all during the session (aka call).
> 2. Channel-Call-UUID is either the same as Unique-ID or the Unique-ID of the session you're bridged to by looking at the source code.
> 3. sip_call_id will be the sip call_id of an inbound/outbound SIP call, More than likely the outbound would match Unique-ID and on
>      inbound it would be what ever the remote party sets/sends.

Comment: I find things a bit different. follow topic in mailing list. anyway thanks.